# How to programmatically end editing of a CTreeCtrl?

Tags: mfc, winapi

I have a class derived from CTreeCtrl. In some circumstances the user might be editing it and I would like to programmatically cancel the edit which is currently in progress.

How do I do this? There doesn't seem to be any appropriate function of the class which would do that, or if I have to send it some message it's not immediately obvious to me what the message is that I should send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is possible by sending the tree control the [TVM_ENDEDITLABELNOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773564(VS.85).aspx) message, or by using the [TreeView_EndEditLabelNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773798(v=VS.85).aspx) macro.

Comment: Huh, and there is an EndEditLabelNow() method of CTreeCtrl. I must be going blind in my old age... thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the user is editing a label, you have to wait for the folling messages:
`TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` and `TVN_ENDLABELEDIT`.

To cancel, just set the focus to another node.

Comment: Yes, I know what TVN_ENDLABELEDIT is, but I wanted to know how I get the edit control to generate one of those. I appreciate the focus suggestion, although that seems slightly awkward - I have to find another node (which potentially might not exist) and then I don't really want it focused afterwards... thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

So I've eventually discovered that I can fake an Escape button press to the edit control:

```
tree.GetEditControl()->SendMessage(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ESCAPE, 1);
```

This seems to cancel editing appropriately.